# Xamarin Android Menu Bar repeats iteslf

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Android project that contains a menu bar. I'm almost certain this was working correctly yesterday, but since then, every time I click on a menu bar item such as 'settings', which takes me to the Settings Activity, then go back to the Main activity, the menu bar items are repeating themselves.

So where i just had 'Settings' and 'help', i not have 2 settings, and 2 help items. If i do it again, i will have 3 of each.

I'm assuming this is something to do with the onPause() and onResume() methods as the app goes to another activity. But i can't see where i'm going wrong (i'm new to Android)

My code for generating the menu bar in the Main Activity is:

```
public override bool OnPrepareOptionsMenu(IMenu menu1)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.myMenuBar, menu1);
        return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu1);
    }




    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item) //do something when an options item is pressed
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
        case Resource.Id.settingsItem:
            showSettings ();
            return true;
        case Resource.Id.helpItem:
            //do something
            return true;
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Any ideas on this would be appreciated. I'm sure it's something fairly simple but I don't know what.

Comment: It has nothing to do with onPause() and onResume() methods. Have you checked Xamarin's support forum? Perhaps its a bug reported there...

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have to clear the menu

```
public override bool OnPrepareOptionsMenu(IMenu menu1)
{
    menu1.clear();
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.myMenuBar, menu1);
    return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu1);
}
```

And perhaps you should inflate the menu in the `OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu, MenuInflater)` method. `OnPrepareOptionsMenu(IMenu)` is meant for enabling/disabling and dynamically modifying items.